# How to keep sliding website on page while lightbox is open?

Tags: javascript, slider, lightbox

Code: http://cssdeck.com/labs/xpwki4sy

Is there any way to keep the main website on slide two when the lightbox is open? Currently the main slider page shifts when you flip images in the lightbox using the arrow keys, there is no problem is the arrows within the lightbox are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `line 1216` of your JS, the FullPage plugin moves the page according to arrow keys. You want that to be avoided when the popup is open.

When the popup is open, it adds elements to the page, and one of them is a div with a class `.mfp-wrap`. So only move the page when this element does not exist:

*line 1216 of your JS*

```
//left
case 37:
    if(!$('.mfp-wrap').length) FP.moveSlideLeft();
    break;

//right
case 39:
    if(!$('.mfp-wrap').length) FP.moveSlideRight();
    break;
```

#### Updated demo

Comment: Another option, without having to modify the plugin, is making use of the function `$.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false)` whenever you open your lightbox and call it again with a `true` parameter whenever you close it.

Comment: @Alvaro Nice alternative. I was not familiar with this function, so I tried modifying the plugin directly, even though it's a little hacky.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, that's a great fix too!